# How I can turn off reportGeneralTypeIssues in lsp pyright?

Tags: python, neovim, language-server-protocol, pyright

Below my lspconfig in nvim, I need to turn off reportGeneralTypeIssues, but when I set it to "none" it doesn't work, how I can fix that ?

```lua
local on_attach = require("plugins.configs.lspconfig").on_attach
local capabilities = require("plugins.configs.lspconfig").capabilities

local lspconfig = require("lspconfig")

-- if you just want default config for the servers then put them in a table
local servers = { "html", "cssls", "tsserver", "clangd", "rust_analyzer", "pyright" }

for _, lsp in ipairs(servers) do
    lspconfig[lsp].setup({
        on_attach = on_attach,
        capabilities = capabilities,
    })
end

--
lspconfig.pyright.setup({
    settings = {
        python = {
            analysis = {
                reportGeneralTypeIssues = "none"
        
            },
        },
    },
})
```